# MoDisco: Can I create KDM model from only part of Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, reverse-engineering, modeling

I'm trying to reverse engineer a big legacy project with MoDisco eclipse plugin. Tried doing a Java to KDM model discovery, but it failed because Java heap space got filled. So i increased the amount of memory, but now discovery process seems to be getting stuck at "Saving discovered model".

If i go and select single Java package from my project, only option i get for discovery is "KDM source" and that one doesn't contain any information about class relations etc.

Is there a way to create a KDM model from only some small part of Java project? Or is there some way to improve KDM discovery performance, when dealing with huge project?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what does huge mean in this case? How many files and how many LOC does your project have?

Comment: 1100 .java source files, about 15MB of size.

Comment: Uh, that's small actually. Would it be an option to use another tool?

Comment: Ok. But that actually just rises question: How can MoDisco perform so poorly? I mean, it's supposed to be designed for reverse engineering of legacy software and legacy apps tend to be quite large projects, right? If my project is actually relatively small, MoDisco should have no problem handling it.

Comment: Well, I'm certainly biased as I work for Yatta Solutions, but maybe you should give [UML Lab](http://www.uml-lab.com/uml-lab/tutorials/reverse-engineering-tutorial/) a try. You can simply drag a Java package into a class diagram with it.

Comment: Do you only need to obtain some visualization of the classes? Do you require a formal underlying model?... If it's the former I'm currently using [ObjectAid](http://goo.gl/9VFj2E) to such things.